# REST practicices on PHP, rewrite and http-verbs

Tags: php, apache, rest, url-rewriting

I'm implementing a REST service in php.

q1. Can I split the controller and resource?

```
http://myserver/myCtrl.php?res=/items/1
```

q2. if not, is the standard specs (if any exists) for rewrites on iis, apache, nginx etc to survive the http-verb over the rewrite?

If not, how to solve?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For APIs (I have a framework for such) I tend to have a URL structure that looks as follows:

**http://domain.com/api/[*resource*]/[*id*]/[*subresource*]**

I pass all requests to a front controller with a **.htaccess** file that parses incoming requests and passes the request off to the relavant controller. So my **index.php** looks similar to the following at the very simplest:

```
<?php

$request = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

$resource_name = ucfirst($request[0]).'Controller';
$http_verb = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

$controller = new $resource_name;

$response = call_user_func_array(array($controller, $http_verb), array($request));

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);
```

So if you call **http://domain.com/api/news**, then it will attempt to instantiate a class called `NewsController`, and if it's a **GET** request then the `get()` method of that class, or `post()` for a **POST** request, and so on. The response of that call is then returned to the client as JSON.

Hopefully that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks, it does make sense that the verb should survive the mod_rewrite.

Comment: Yeah. Best thing about using the default implementation is you don't have to do anything special in your PHP code to handle it.

Comment: can you post your htaccess? Reading your code when you do `$resource_name = ucfirst($request[0]).'Controller';` it should load the apiController because api is the first item of request_uri

Answer (score 2):

I had some of the same questions and found this video pretty helpful (not standards, but good practices):

http://blog.apigee.com/detail/slides_for_restful_api_design_second_edition_webinar/

I implemented my rest service by rewriting the urls through .htaccess files (mod_rewrite) and a central dispatcher so it looks like this:

`http://myserver/myctrl/resource/1`

My .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Read more about rewrite: 
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

I have an index file that does pretty much what Martin outlined. I explode on "/" and assume first is controller, second is action, and the rest are parameters.

Comment: Thanks. (But >50 min to describe REST? Not very restful...)